# How to check if variable is set in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a `terraform` module with `dynamic` block. But that dynamic block ONLY has to be created if some variables are set.

Here's my `variable.tf` looks like:

```
variable "apim_named_values" {
  type = map(object({
    display_name       = string
    named_value        = optional(string)
    secret             = bool
    secret_id          = optional(string)
    identity_client_id = optional(string)
  }))
  description = "Map of named values to be used with the APIM Management"

  default = {}
}
```

And here's my `module.tf` looks like:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_named_value" "named_values" {
  for_each = var.apim_named_values

  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = local.rg_name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  display_name        = each.value.display_name
  value               = try(each.value.named_value, null)

  secret = each.value.secret

  dynamic "value_from_key_vault" {
    for_each = can(each.value.secret_id) ? [1] : []
    content {
      secret_id          = each.value.secret_id
      identity_client_id = each.value.identity_client_id
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how my `main.tf` looks like:

```
module "apim-main" {
  source              = "../../modules/resources/my-apim"
  . . .

  apim_named_values = {
    "value1" = {
      display_name       = "My Display Name"
      named_value        = "My Value"
      secret             = false
      secret_id          = "/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/key-vault/secrets/secret-name"
    }
    "value2" = {
      display_name = "Another Display Name"
      named_value  = "My Value"
      secret       = false
    }
    "value3" = {
      display_name = "Yet Another Display Name"
      secret       = false
      named_value  = "My Other Value"
    }
  }
  . . . 

}
```

What I want to do here is, if **ONLY** `secret_id` or `identity_client_id` is set, then create the dynamic block `value_from_key_vault`

I am using the `can(each.value.secret_id)` to check if it exists or not, but the problem is it is giving me the following error:

> "value_from_key_vault": only one of `value,value_from_key_vault` can be specified, but `value,value_from_key_vault` were specified.

Can someone help me understand this and how to fix it?

Comment: If only `secret_id` or `identity_client_id` can be set, why does your `value1` have both of them? Its confusing what do you want to do.

Comment: `identity_client_id` is optional. I have update the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Terraform objects, unset attributes are represented by `null`. You've tried to use [the `can` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/can) here, but `can(each.value.secret_id)` will always return `true` because `secret_id` is declared as part of this object type and so that attribute is guaranteed to be present.

Because it's common in Terraform to use a value that might be null to represent the situation where there could be *zero or one* of something, Terraform has a concise operator for that which is written `[*]` and is called [the "splat" operator](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat). Specifically, I'm referring to its [Single Values as Lists](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat#single-values-as-lists) feature.

Here's how you could use that in your situation:

```
  dynamic "value_from_key_vault" {
    for_each = each.value.secret_id[*]
    content {
      secret_id          = each.value.secret_id
      identity_client_id = each.value.identity_client_id
    }
  }
```

`each.value.secret_id[*]` has two possible results:

- If `each.value.secret_id` is set, its result is a single-element list containing the value of that attribute.
- If `each.value.secret_id` is unset (that is, if it's `null`), the result is an empty list.

---

You mentioned in your question that this block should be present if *either* `secret_id` or `identity_client_id` is set. A typical way to represent a situation like that would be to echo the heirarchical structure of the resource schema in your input variable by using a nested object type, like this:

```
variable "apim_named_values" {
  type = map(object({
    display_name = string
    named_value  = optional(string)
    secret       = bool
    from_key_vault = optional(object({
      secret_id          = optional(string)
      identity_client_id = optional(string)
    }))
  }))
  description = "Map of named values to be used with the APIM Management"
}
```

Adding this extra nested object adds some new information you can use: the `from_key_vault` attribute *itself* could be either set or `null`, independently of the attributes inside.

That means you can use whether that attribute is set as the basis for how many `value_from_key_vault` blocks to generate, like this:

```
  dynamic "value_from_key_vault" {
    for_each = each.value.from_key_vault[*]
    content {
      secret_id          = value_from_key_vault.value.secret_id
      identity_client_id = value_from_key_vault.value.identity_client_id
    }
  }
```

Notice that the `content` block now refers to `value_from_key_vault.value` instead of `each.value`. `value_from_key_vault` here refers to the current element of the *nested* iteration in this `dynamic` block, and so it effectively refers to the object that was assigned to the `from_key_vault` attribute.

---

You could optionally use a custom validation rule on your input variable to catch some other potential problems:

```
variable "apim_named_values" {
  type = map(object({
    display_name = string
    named_value  = optional(string)
    secret       = bool
    from_key_vault = optional(object({
      secret_id          = optional(string)
      identity_client_id = optional(string)
    }))
  }))
  description = "Map of named values to be used with the APIM Management"

  validation {
    condition     = var.apim_named_values.from_key_vault == null || var.named_value == null
    error_message = "Cannot set both named_value and from_key_vault."
  }

  validation {
    condition = (
      var.apim_named_values.from_key_vault != null ?
      var.from_key_vault.secret_id != null || var.from_key_vault.identity_client_id != null :
      true
    )
    error_message = "If from_key_vault is set, at least one of the nested secret_id and identity_client_id attributes must be set."
  }
}
```

This will return a custom error if the user of this module makes either of the following usage errors:

- Leaving both `named_value` and `from_key_vault` unset.
- Setting `from_key_vault = {}`, thereby leaving both of the nested attributes unset.

I'm not sure if either of those situations is *actually* incorrect usage, but I've included this part because the question seems to imply that exactly one of these must be set, in which case custom variable validation is a good idea to give better feedback if someone uses the module incorrectly.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you Martin for the awesome input! <3